# Cakephp belongsTo relationship - accessing related Model

Tags: cakephp

I have a consultant table that has a foreign key 'specialty_id' which is linked to a 'specilaties' table.

```
class Consultant extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Specialty' => array(
            'className'     => 'Specialty',
            'conditions'    => array('Specialty.active' => 1)
        )
    );
}

class Specialty extends AppModel {
    public $hasOne = 'Consultant';
}
```

I think this is right, however, i am unable to get a list of specialties from the consultant controller 
("Call to a member function find() on a non-object  ")

```
$this->set('specialties', $this->Specialty->find('all'));
```

Where abouts am i going wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember you are in the *controller*, not in the model. Try this:

```
$this->set('specialties', $this->Consultant->Specialty->find('all'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Model in other controller then, first load that model and then run query:

```
$this->loadModel('Specialty');
```